# Cheese camera problem in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: camera, 14.10, cheese

There is a problem with Cheese on my computer. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 (everything is upgraded to the last version ). As seen here:

> Kernel version : 3.17.1-031701-generic
>
> Cheese version : 3.12.2

Whenever I take a picture, the picture is black using Cheese of course, but I do not have a problem with videos.

What is my problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using guvcview?

Comment: yes, and everything's working so fine, but i prefer cheese. Everyting was working before i update my ubuntu to 14.10 ( form 14.04) i dont know why..

Comment: what happens if you run cheese from the command line? Are there errors?

Comment: I got only some gtk errors :s so nothing important i guess

Comment: What webcam model do you have? The output of lsusb might be helpful.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b071 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheese 3.10 ships with Ubuntu 14.04, while Cheese 3.12 ships with Ubuntu 14.10. This may explain why it stopped working.

Try this:

```
 sudo apt-get remove cheese
 sudo echo "deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cheese.list
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now install cheese 3.10 with Synaptic. If you don't have Synaptic yet, you can install it:

```
 sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Force the version like so:
Package -> Force version (choose 3.10)

To fix broken packages, close Synaptic and do this:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

Don't forget this:

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cheese.list
 sudo apt-get update
```

Now it should work. Never update Cheese again. :) This is a [guide to lock the version](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/).

Although this method is not recommended to apply for every package, it may provide a workaround for your problem.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working, when i force install cheese 3.10 using synaptic, its says that i have to repair broken packages first.. and the borken one is cheese :S

Comment: See my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Still not working :s i got the same thing..

Comment: What's the output of apt-get -f install? (you will need to do the steps over, except for the step "installing synaptic")

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: I got no output when i do "apt-get -f install", i removed my ubuntu 14.10 and installed ubuntu gnome 14.10 (removed everything i had before) and still have the same bug with cheese :s

Comment: It seems the only option you have is to install 14.04 instead. Or use alternatives to Cheese.

Comment: It's working on Ubuntu 14.04, thank you